# DynaPDF Compatibility with Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am looking to use the [DynaPDF](http://www.dynaforms.com/index.htm) in my Android project as a C library. However on the downloads page the only option I can see that could be used is "DynaPDF for linux for x86 (32)", as I understand it x86 is based on architecture where as Android use ARM architecture. I am quite new to native programming and so would appreciate if somebody could confirm was I guess or explain another way to implement the library.

Comment: I really thought somebody would know the answer to this

Comment: What do you mean by "implement"? You already have the source of DynaPDF and you want to port it to Android? Or you want to build from scratch a library that has the same functionality as DynaPDF?

Comment: I want to port it to Android and use the library that they have already wrote

Comment: To port it you need the source -- do they give it? From the Download page (http://download.dynaforms.de/DownloadPage) it seems that they only give compiled libraries (which are not very useful for porting).

Comment: thank you gfour. I will contact them directly (as maybe I should have done originally): Write it as an answer and I can award you the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To port the library, you must have access to the sources (the download page of DynaPDF has links to the compiled libraries, which is not very useful).